# Spring+ Hibernate insert to DB triggered 3 times if restart or first run server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I connect spring hibernate and i have some probem. If i restart tomcat server or run app first time my insert to DB triggered 3 times. Next insert work normaly. I not understent why.

My controler:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(100);
        user.setFirstName("Foo");
        user.setLastName("Boo");
        user.setAge(27);
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        userDao.addUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My DAO:

```
public interface UserDao {

    boolean addUser(User user);

    User getUser(long userId);

    boolean updateUser(User user);

    boolean deleteUser(User user);


}
```

and

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    HibernateSessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        session.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(long userId) {
        Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        User user = (User) session.createCriteria(User.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("userId", userId))
                .uniqueResult();

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateUser(User user) {
        Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        session.update(user);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteUser(User user) {
        Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        session.delete(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

if i run server open this link `http://localhost:8080/` and in the browser i see `Hello world!` and in my DB insert 3 row. Then if i press `F5` insert 1 row to DB.

Comment: Please try with curl commands on terminal. May browser requests thrice. Please provide database config.

Comment: if i tried http://localhost:8080/1 (wrong link) i get HTTP Status 404  but in DB insert 1 row

Comment: Can you post the entire example with all config ?